# Git - Get merged timestamp based on commit id

Tags: git, merge, timestamp, gerrit

I am trying to get the timestamp when a particular commit was merged to master.

When I do git log, it shows me the author timestamp i.e. the timestamp when the commit was first created.

I can also see the committer timestamp, i.e. the timestamp when the commit was last updated. But I do not see the timestamp when the commit was merged to the master. (This will be different from committer timestamp based on the code reviews or any other delays that might happen after the last commit was made).

Does git even store the merge-timestamp anywhere or is it not possible?

My attempt:

I tried using `git show <commitid> --stat` but this also shows only author timestamp.

Secondly, I did `git log --format=fuller` and this enlists the following:

```
Author:     abc
AuthorDate: Mon Jun 13 12:27:59 2016 -0500
Commit:     abc
CommitDate: Mon Jun 13 14:32:21 2016 -0500
```

No trace of when the commit was actually merged.

Comment: @PetSerAl Why are you including `--all`? The question only asks to know when it merged to master. Also, `--topo-order` seem extraneous since `--ancestry-path` will only show a single line of ancestry anyway. Lastly, `--reverse` will have no effect when combined with `-n 1` because reverse is only applied _after_ the result set is limited to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Make an alias (feel free to use your own alias name):

```
git config --global alias.merge-commit '!f(){ for r in $(git rev-list ${2:-HEAD} --first-parent); do ! git merge-base --is-ancestor $1 $r && git rev-list --first-parent $r..${2:-HEAD} --reverse | head -1 | git log --stdin -1 ${*:3} && break; done; }; f'
```

Example Usage: (Default is HEAD)

```
git merge-commit commit
git merge-commit commit another-branch
git merge-commit commit another-branch --format=fuller
```